# Pull variables from separate function

Tags: php, scope

If I have two public functions and I want to pull a variable from one inside of another, what is the best way to accomplish this? I know about 'global' but this method seems like it could cause me problems down the road.

Imagine I have something like this:

```
class myCMS {

   public function process_apples() {

   $a = $_POST['$apples'];

   }

   public function display_apples() {

   echo $a;

   }
}
```

How would I go about using `display_apples()` to report $a from `process_apples()`? Im new to PHP, so feel free to let me know if I am violating some best practicing for organizing my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two methods in a class, and want a variable to shared between them, you should use a [**class property**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) -- which is kind of a variable that's inside a class.

Your class would then look like this :

```
class myCMS {
    protected $a;   // declare the property (won't be visible from outside the class)

    public function process_apples() {
        $this->a = $_POST['$apples'];
    }

    public function display_apples() {
        echo $this->a;
    }
}
```

And a couple of notes :

- You need to use `$this->property_name` to access a property
- Not related, but you should generally no use `$_POST` from inside your class : it makes your class dependent on external global variables *-- of course, up to you to determine whether it's a problem or not.*

Comment: I would recommend to use a private variable instead of protected as the other two answers have posted.  You should always try to limit the scope as much as possible and open it up more later on if necessary.  And here in this case, there is no need for any child classes to access the variables so therefore the variable should be private.  (Sorry for the babble, but all I'm trying to say is change protected to private.)

Comment: I will not enter in the protected vs private debate ; but thanks for pointing out the OP should think about visibility :-)

Answer (score 1):

You would have:

```
class myCMS {

   private $a;

   public function process_apples() {

     $this->a = $_POST['$apples'];
     // process

   }

   public function display_apples() {

     echo $this->a;    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a class, you could make a private class variable, like this:

```
class myCMS {
    private $a;

    public function process_apples() {
        $this->a = $_POST['$apples'];
    }

    public function display_apples() {
        echo $this->a;
    }
}
```